# Vapor & Heroku : How to

Tags: heroku, vapor

Is there some commands to reload your current schema on your Heroku PostgreSQL databse ?

***vapor run prepare*** work fine locally, but i didn't find a way to do that on Heroku

Answer (score 0):

The [Release Phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) functionality may help you.  If you're using Review Apps, or Heroku Buttons, consider the [postdeploy script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#the-postdeploy-script).

Answer (score 0):

When you use the [Heroku Vapor Buildpack](https://github.com/vapor/heroku-buildpack) you shouldn't really call `vapor run prepare` yourself. Instead, you should prepare your `Droplet` instance within the `main.swift` file or using some helper method, depending on how you want to structure your code.

```
let drop = Droplet()
// ...
drop.preparations.append(MyModel.self)
// ...
drop.run()
```